# Spring HandlerInterceptor via annotation instead of via addInterceptor

Tags: spring

When I add a HandlerInterceptor in Spring I need to add the Interceptor in a Spring config like so:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(myHandlerInterceptor)
            .addPathPatterns("/api/**");
}
```

I am missing some way of configuring it via annotation like this:

```
@HandlerInterceptor(pathPattern = "/api/**")
public class MyHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
   // impl
}
```

This way I wouldn't have to add an extra Spring config for it. Is this not possible or never thought of? Does anyone know?

I guess it is kind of a question to the Spring framework, but I could also be missing something